# Perl Win32 - Geting file handle provided file and removing it

Tags: perl

I have a file (ex. C:\temp\afile.txt) in which a Windows service has an open file handle on. After stopping the process, the file handle remains open. I would like to be able to find and delete this handle simply provided the file name and path with a Perl script. Is this possible? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions, questions, confusion :)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to locate which process hold a file handle open and to reach into the process and kill the handle because MS's [`Process Explorer`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can do just this. How? I don't know.

You should probably use [`MoveFileEx(file_name, NULL, MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead. This causes the file to be deleted the next time the system is rebooted.

[Win32API::File](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32API%3a%3aFile) provides a Perl interface to that system call.

Comment: Issue here is that the file cannot be deleted as it is a log and the process that owns the log will roll it over on next start of process. So I would need to remove the file handle without actually affecting the file. Ironically, I am currently using Process Explorer to do this manually but I would like to automate this :) Thank you for your answer though.